# What happens if all setTimeout IDs are used?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Calling the `setTimeout` function will return an integer ID so that `clearTimeout` can be called with that ID.

What happens if `setTimeout` gets called more times than there are positive integers in JavaScript? Is there a security issue?

Comment: The browser will stop. Why you asked smt. like going to never happen thing?

Comment: A blackhole will form and humanity will be turned into a nothingness. One hand will continue clapping, though. Oddest thing.

Comment: What are you doing that risks this happening?

Comment: @Quentin: I'm trying to [hack Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/announcing-pwnium-2.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the relevant code in Chrome:

```
static int timeoutId()
{
    static int lastUsedTimeoutId = 0;
    ++lastUsedTimeoutId;
    // Avoid wraparound going negative on us.
    if (lastUsedTimeoutId <= 0)
        lastUsedTimeoutId = 1;
    return lastUsedTimeoutId;
}
```

Thus, Last ID will be just 1 after no positive integers remaining.

Answer (score 3):

You'll run out of memory (or some other resource) long before that happens. Javascript numbers are 64 bit floats, which can accurately represent integers up to 2^52, which means it takes 32 petabytes of memory to even hold that many IDs, let alone accompanying objects or tasks.

Answer (score 1):

On my 32 bit windows 7 system with Chrome 21, the tab with the page crashed after about 4295063. But it was only the tab. I closed that tab and everything else was working normally.

Opera 12 the script runs slower and slower.

Firefox complains about that the script is taking to much time.

You can test for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/some/r58s8/